# Optimize query to return row count

Tags: mysql, sql, optimization

I am trying to get latest date for each item.

For e.g.

Say I have a table with vendor, item, shipment Date. I am retrieving latest date for each item shipped by all vendors.

Data:

```
|Vendor|item   |shipmentDate|
|HP    |laptop | 2014/07/29 |
|HP    |laptop | 2014/06/28 |
|Apple |tablet | 2014/05/05 |
|Apple |tablet | 2014/06/28 |
```

Get latest date query:

```
SELECT Vendor, item, MAX(shipmentDate) 
FROM table 
GROUP BY Vendor, item;
```

Result:

```
|Vendor|item   |shipmentDate|
|HP    |laptop | 2014/07/29 |
|Apple |tablet | 2014/06/28 |
```

Everything is fine. However, my actual table would yield more than 50,000 records for above query. So I am trying to execute the query in a batch from my JAVA application. Thus, I am trying to retrieve row count of data:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM (SELECT Vendor, item, MAX(shipmentDate) 
    FROM table 
    GROUP BY Vendor, item) T;
```

Row Count query takes: 00:04:47 same amount of time as the other query: 00:04:43. Looking to find a way to optimize the row count query. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try doing this:

```
select count(distinct vendor, item)
from table;
```

This *might* be faster with an index on `table(vendor, item)`.  I am not 100% if MySQL will take advantage of the index for this query.

Comment: the distinct query was taking same amount of time as the other query. But after creating index it ran faster. Thanks.. :)

Comment: @Sas . . . Hence, MySQL *does* use an index for `count(distinct)` when there are multiple columns.

Answer (score 1):

I only want to suggest using DISTINCT to get the count, maybe it yields better results:

```
select count(Vendor) from
(select distinct Vendor, item
from  table)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use MySQL's non-standard SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS option for this.

First query:

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS Vendor, item, MAX(shipmentDate) 
FROM table 
GROUP BY Vendor, item;
```

Second query:

```
SELECT FOUND_ROWS();
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to run only the query

```
    SELECT Vendor, item, MAX(shipmentDate) 
    FROM table 
    GROUP BY Vendor, item
```

and put the result in a ResultSet (if you are using Java), meaning store them in a Table like data structure (cache them) and them using the in-built methods of the API, count the number of rows in the ResultSet or table.

This will be faster than running the query twice.

Comment: the reason I needed to get row count and query in a batch to avoid running out of memory when trying to query large data. So this won't solve the problem